# glow button onfocus

Tags: jquery, css, html

i want button to have glow effect when selected by tab key. can any one help me with this. code snippet will be very helpful.

thanks
rashmi

Comment: What type of 'glow' do you want? An outline, or a change in the background-color to a brighter shade?

Comment: @David outline glow around button.is that possible to have both effects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you're developing for modern browsers you can use the html5 box shadow and transition:

```
button{
 background:#000;   
 color:#fff;
 border:none;
 transition:box-shadow .3s linear;
 -moz-transition:-moz-box-shadow .3s linear;
 -webkit-transition:-webkit-box-shadow .3s linear;
}
button:hover,button:focus{
 box-shadow:0px 0px 15px #fff;
 -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 15px #fff;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 15px #fff;   
}
```

demo:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/ybHUy/

Comment: Hover doesn't include focus from the keyboard according to W3C.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JQuery for this.

```
#yourButtonId:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #fff;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #fff;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(color=#ffffff,strength=3) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#999999,direction=135, strength=5)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(color=#ffffff,strength=3) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#999999,direction=135, strength=5);
}
```

Note that I'd put the MSIE equivalents in a conditional comment on a real site so that when IE9 supports box-shadow it won't use the filter fallbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers support html5 animations but you could have a look at  http://colorpowered.com/blend/ .

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery for it can be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#yourButtonId')
        .focus(function () {
            $(this).addClass('yourGlowClass');
        })
        .blur(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('yourGlowClass');
        });
});
```

A demo of the JQuery: http://www.jsfiddle.net/S2H2R/3/.

I'm not 100% sure about the CSS Filter, but there's an [tutorial on the CSS Filter, including glow](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_text_effects.htm), which should be useful for the class to store in your css file.

Comment: @rashmi here's an example of the JQuery, http://www.jsfiddle.net/S2H2R/3/, but it uses a background change for the css, rather than the glow effect

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?
[YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example13.html)
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example13.html